# netflix zuul1, a strange phenomenon of uploading large files with multipart file?

Tags: java, large-files, netflix-zuul

My project uses zuul1, has a file upload module, and the client call interface, as others have reported, is http://zuul-proxy/zuul/upload-module/file

However, I found that when the file is large, the response package is not normal, which causes nginx to think that the response is not normal and wait for a timeout. From this curl, you can see that the terminal will be linked
[url http://ip:port/zuul/upload-module  failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyovF.png)

But if the request http://zuul-proxy/upload-module/file is normal
[url http://ip:port/upload-module  success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5S32.png)

Very strange problem, after analysis when using zuul in the url will skip the DispatcherServlet, should be related to this, but do not know how to solve?

use zuul prefix will skip the DispatcherServlet, which leads to the above problem

And if i config zuul.servlet-path = /,   Whether used or not "zuul" prefix will go wrong.

I guess I skipped the DispatcherServlet but didn't know how to solve it

Please help

Comment: The reason I want to fix this problem is because my zuul is being brokered by nginx, which is consider this is exception package, and finally  the service times out

Comment: Do not use images for text information. Add the information as text in the question and not as links. And what is a `response package`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.